# Tensorflow object detection: cropping large input images into tiles

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have a skewed image of 1100x250 pixels, and some small labels boxes of 30x30. My coco model isn't training well, probably because everything gets resized to 300x300.

Some people on the internet suggest cropping my training images to be closer to 300x300 (so making tiles of my photo), and of course create the relevant annotation files.

However, I don't find official information about this, nor scientific papers. Is this the way to go?

- Do I show all the tiles to my model when training, even though I know there are no object in there? (no annotations) Or do I only show the tiles with bounding boxes?
- Do I crop evenly at 300x300, which makes the last tile smaller (thus stretched out more than the others)? Or do I try to keep an aspect ratio similar for every tile?
- Do I need more training samples per tile? Right now I have about 500 images labeled, but over the entire span of 1100 pixels. Do I need 500 instances per tile?
- Someone suggested cropping 300x300 around each labeled object, but to my mind tensorflow will just learn "oh it's always in the middle" which is not what I want

Thanks for helping, I feel like this is a bit underexplained on the internet.

Comment: I think this is a good solution to your problem. I would show all tiles to the model, having more example, even negative ones is always good. GCD(1100, 250) is 50. Do 50x50 tiles which you can resize to 300x300. I don't understand your third point... I don't think that cropping arround your bounding boxes would be a good idea. How do you intend to handle tile boundaries? Crop your label boxes? Remove them?

Comment: @AlexisBRENON I hadn't tought about GCD, that does seem a good idea to use that number. For the third point, instead of cropping evenly like "every 50x50", the suggestion was "for each bounding box, crop a square around it to make sure you have it" (putting the box in the middle always). In my idea of tiling, I would have some overlap between tiles, like 20 pixels, and hope for the best of keeping as many annotations as possible..

Comment: Cropping around bbox was your fourth point. I did not understand what you mean by "500 instances per tile". If you have 500 images, make 100*100 tiles with 25px overlap on each sides (up to you to handle image boundaries), you will have `500 * (1+(250-100)/75) * (1+(1100-100/75))` which is about 22500 tiles, some with labels, some not. Let us know what you choose and if it is a good solution.

Comment: @AlexisBRENON right, sorry, i didn't reread to count :-) I do have many tiles then, but since a lot won't have anything on them, I was wondering if I could use them. The image I'm processing is from a fixed camera, but the objects can be anywhere on the image. I was afraid that TF would look more at the background than the actual object to identify. I'll just try it I guess ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, using images with nothing on them will learn your model to differentiate objects from background, avoiding too much false positives.

Answer (score 2):

FYI here is a scholar paper to reference:
http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPRW_2019/papers/UAVision/Unel_The_Power_of_Tiling_for_Small_Object_Detection_CVPRW_2019_paper.pdf

We are in the same boat, I'm also working with the SSD Mobilenet CNN with 300x300 input tensors. SSD is just not great at this, no matter what approach you take. I've not tried to do anything to tweak the model, but at the application level, I've tried tried a couple of approaches:

- Tiling images into uniform tiles before feeding it into the model. For instance: 
  a 900x900 image may be fed into the model like this:

```
             1
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
          900x900
```

and be split like this:

```
     1           2           3
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
  300x300

     4           5           6
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------| 

    7            8           9
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------| 
|---------| |---------| |---------|
```

[Edit] I make the tile size configurable, it does not need to be exactly 300x300.

- Selective tiling, but first finding some region of interest. This approach is similar to the top one, but you first looks for some type way to detect a regions that you know for sure will have objects and only focus on those regions. The approach I went with for finding those regions is to find object contours, this could easily be done by adding some erosion to the image and then grab bounding boxes around it, similar to [this](https://github.com/Namburger/aspect). Those bounding boxes can then be resized to fit tensor shapes and pass on the model for inference!

I got better results for both methods, but obviously it requires much more inference than a single pass. There are also the post processing question on how to deal with overlapping objects from 2 different tiles and put them all together. That is another problem though, you can look at algorithms like nonmax suppression for things like that!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I had already found the paper in the meantime too. I use their approach of cutting up into tiles, with some overlap, also taking into account the average size of the bounding boxes to know what tilesize to cut to. It's not perfect, but it's something 'good enough' for me.

Comment: We in our firm have implemented tiling approach and have got improvement of more than 50% precision recall for most of our labels. We will open source the functionality soon.

Comment: The examples I spoked about ended up being here: https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/blob/master/examples/small_object_detection.py :)